# Running the command line dot program from a Qt application generates no output, what is wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, svg, dot

I have an app that generates a `dependencies.dot` file which I then want to convert to an SVG image.

When I do that from a simple application like so:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    system("dot -Tsvg ../BUILD/dependencies.dot > ../BUILD/dependencies.svg");

    return 0;
}
```

It works great. The SVG image is present and working.

When I instead run it from my Qt application, the SVG file is created (by the shell), but it remains empty.

Any idea what could prevent `dot` from outputting data to its `stdout`?

Just in case, I also tried a `cat` to send the input through `stdin` instead of a filename:

```
system("cat ../BUILD/dependencies.dot | dot -Tsvg > ../BUILD/dependencies.svg");
```

And that didn't make any differences.

Also using the full path (`/usr/bin/dot`) did not help either.

Another test, I tried to use `popen()` and the first `fread()` immediately returns 0 (i.e. the mark of EOF).

It may not be Qt, but something is interacting with `dot`'s ability to do anything. Any pointers on why that is would be wonderful.

Maybe an important note? I start my app. from a console, so `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` should all work as expected. I actually can see debug logs appearing there and other apps seem to work just as expected (i.e. My Qt app. can successfully run `make`, for example).

Here is an example of the resulting SVG (when I don't run it from within my Qt app):

[image]

---

For reference, the source code can be found on github. This is part of the snapbuilder. A tool that I use to run a build on launchpad. It's still incomplete, but it's getting there.

https://github.com/m2osw/snapcpp/tree/master/snapbuilder

The specific function to look for: `project::generate_svg()`.

Comment: Probably different current working directory (not the directory contain your program) so the relative path `../BUILD/dependencies.dot` is wrong

Comment: @RichardCritten Just in case, I added `pwd; ` at the start of the command and went ahead and removed the `> ...output...`. I see the current working directory printed in the console, but nothing from `dot`. There is something that prevents `dot` from doing anything... weird.

Comment: Also redirect stderr maybe it contains something useful.

Comment: @albert I see I did not reply. There's absolutely nothing in stdout or stderr...

Answer (score 0):

I still have no clue what side effect Qt has on `system()` that the `dot` command would fail. However, if using my own `fork()` + `execve()`, then it works.

I wanted a new [process class](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher/tree/main/cppprocess) for my environment, so I implemented that. This newer version is using FIFOs or directly opening closing files that it passes to the process.

```
...

// write the script in `std::stringstream dot` then:
//
std::string script(dot.str());
g_dot_process = std::make_shared<cppprocess::process>("dependencies");

g_dot_process->set_command("/usr/bin/dot");
g_dot_process->add_argument("-Tsvg");
g_dot_process->add_input(cppprocess::buffer_t(script.data(),
                                              script.data() + script.length()));
g_dot_process->set_capture_output();
g_dot_process->set_output_capture_done(output_captured);
g_dot_process->start(); // TODO: check return value for errors

...

// and in output_captured()
//
void snap_builder::svg_ready(std::string const & svg)
{
    std::string const svg_filename(...);

    {
        std::ofstream out;
        out.open(svg_filename);
        if(!out.is_open())
        {
            std::cerr << "error: \n";
            return;
        }
        out.write(svg.c_str(), svg.size());
    }

    dependency_tree->load(QString::fromUtf8(svg_filename.c_str()));
}
```

Now the dot file is generated and displayed as expected.

This is rather strange since most everything else I've done with a simple `system()` call works as expected. There must be something about `stdin` or `stdout` that makes `dot` not do its work.